# Error: INSERT INTO fails mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection, sql-insert

I have a problem with mySQL I get this error

```
Notice: Undefined property: PDO::$error in C:\MAMP\htdocs\paresFiles.php on line 33
Error: INSERT INTO `searchtable`(`word`, `array`, `count`) VALUES ( pinocchio , 1 ,-1)

Notice: Undefined property: PDO::$error in C:\MAMP\htdocs\paresFiles.php on line 33
Error: INSERT INTO `searchtable`(`word`, `array`, `count`) VALUES ( alice's adventures in wonderland , 2 ,-1)

Notice: Undefined property: PDO::$error in C:\MAMP\htdocs\paresFiles.php on line 33
Error: INSERT INTO `searchtable`(`word`, `array`, `count`) VALUES ( peter pan , 3 ,-1)

Notice: Undefined property: PDO::$error in C:\MAMP\htdocs\paresFiles.php on line 33
Error: INSERT INTO `searchtable`(`word`, `array`, `count`) VALUES ( snow white , 4 ,-1)
```

I want to insert to my search table in mysql 3 values and when I insert them I get this error and didn't get any data in my table.
what I need to do to solve this error?

this is my code (for insert data):

```
include_once 'connect.php';

$dir = "storage";
$title;
$auther;
$fileNum;
// Open a directory, and read its contents
foreach (glob($dir."/*.txt") as $filename) {
    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
    if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        if(substr( $line, 0, 3 ) === "#id")
        {
            $fileNum=substr( $line, 5, 3 );
        }
        if(substr( $line, 0, 6 ) === "#title")
        {
            $title=substr( $line, 8, 100 );
        }
        if(substr( $line, 0, 5 ) === "#name")
        {
            $auther=substr( $line, 8, 12 );
        }
    }
    $titleVal=-1;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `searchtable`(`word`, `array`, `count`) VALUES     ($title,$fileNum,$titleVal)";

       if ($db->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $db->error;
        }
    fclose($handle);
 }
```

connect to mysql:

```
<?php
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=search;charset=utf8mb4', 'root', 'root');
    if (!$db) {
        die('Could not connect:' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo 'Connected successfully';
?>
```

Comment: missing quotes in values. Better use prepare statement!!

Comment: like this:  $sql = "INSERT INTO searchtable("word", "array", "count") VALUES ($title,$fileNum,$titleVal)"; ? @Saty

Comment: read http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Use PDO::errorInfo() instead of PDO::$error

Comment: @mnv it writes me Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\MAMP\htdocs\paresFiles.php on line 33
Error: INSERT INTO `searchtable`(`word`, `position`, `count`) VALUES ( pinocchio , 1 ,-1)

Comment: @user3488862 Write something like this: `$db->errorInfo()[2]` Read more about: http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.errorinfo.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use prepare statements.

Something like this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO searchtable (word, array, count) VALUES (:word , :array, :count)";

$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
$statement->exec(array(
    'word' => $title,
    'array' => $fileNum,
    'count' => $titleVal
));
```

Comment: it writes me
 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::exec() in C:\MAMP\htdocs\paresFiles.php:31 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\MAMP\htdocs\paresFiles.php on line 31

Comment: Need to change `exec` to `execute`

Comment: @Saty ok I changed it but now I have a new error: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\MAMP\htdocs\paresFiles.php on line 40
Error: INSERT INTO searchtable (word, position, count) VALUES (:word , :position, :count)
Array

Comment: can you dump the values of `$title`, `$fileNum` and `$titleVal`